# resizing and rounded image on a bootstrap-5 card

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

I want to resize and rounded the image in a bootstrap-5 card but i don't know how to do that using bootstrap-5 or css3, I want the image to be smaller and rounded on a center of this card.

My Template:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    

<div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="card text-center">
                    <img class="rounded" src="https://3.imimg.com/data3/LE/LH/GLADMIN-37134/school-badges-500x500.jpg" alt="">
                    <h1 class="text-primary">{{board.school_name}}</h1>
                    <p>{{board.school_address}}, {{board.location}}</p>
                    <p>P O Box: {{board.p_o_box}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your image is a bad choice as it has a white border around the actual graphic. but see here. i added a `.thumb` class with a width/height. a `align-items-center` on the `.row` and a `.rounded-circle` on the image.

```css
.thumb {
  width: 100px;
  height: auto; // if the image is square, this will be 100px automatically
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    

<div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="card align-items-center">
                    <img class="rounded-circle thumb" src="https://dummyimage.com/300x300/000/fff.jpg" alt="ff">
                    <h1 class="text-primary">{{board.school_name}}</h1>
                    <p>{{board.school_address}}, {{board.location}}</p>
                    <p>P O Box: {{board.p_o_box}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```